# Sequelize query based on results of another sequelize query

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a postgres database and I am using Sequelize. From tables **vehicles** and **bookings** I am trying to get all vehicles available given a startDate and endDate.

If I search Bookings with the give dates using:

```
Bookings.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { dateOut : { [Op.gt]: req.body.startDate} },
            { dateIn : { [Op.lt]: req.body.startDate} }
        ],
        [Op.or]: [
            { dateOut : { [Op.gt]: req.body.endDate} },
            { dateIn : { [Op.lt]: req.body.endDate} }
        ]
    }
})
```

I get all the vehicles that are booked during these dates. For exmple a search with startDate 2020-12-12 and endDate 2020-12-13 gives me these bookings:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "startDate": "2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "vehicleId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "startDate": "2020-12-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2020-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
        "vehicleId": 2
    }
]
```

Is it possible to use Sequelize to return the vehicles from the Vehicles table that are not found in this initial search?

UPDATE

Following Anatoly's answer I have this. It works in response to the results of the first query:

```
.then(bookingData => {
    const bookedVehicleIds = bookingData.map(x => x.vehicleId)

    Vehicles.findAll({
        where: {
            id: {
                [Op.notIn]: bookedVehicleIds
            }
        }
    })
    .then(results => {
        res.send(results);
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no simple way to do one query instead of two ones (only using `NOT EXISTS` subquery via `sequelize.where` and `sequelize.literal`).
So if you already have `Booking` model instances you can just use `Op.notIn` to get all `Vehicles` that have not been booked on a given period:

```js
const bookings = await Bookings.findAll({
 // ... where condition omitted
})
const bookedVehicleIds = bookings.map(x => x.vehicleId)
const notBookedVehicles = await Vehicles.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Op.notIn]: bookedVehicleIds
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I am new to Sequelize and tried to fit your answer into the way I am doing it I have updated my question. It seems to work but I would appreciate an explanation as to where x comes into it.

Comment: `x` just a name of parameter representing one element of an array. You can give it any name you want